# What are special rules to see these strange CSS result in :first-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why are not the results the same?
Both Ps and DIVs have very different results

**HTML Code:**

```css
    p:first-child {
        color: #ff6347;
    }
    
    
    div:first-child {
        color: #8a2be2;
    }
```

```html
   <body> 
        <p> p + p
            <p>Hello</p>
        </p>

        <div> div + p
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>

        <p> p + div
            <div>Hello</div>
        </p>

        <div> div + div
            <div>Hello</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: you cannot put `div` or `p` inside  `p`

Comment: P doesn't accept any element inside it ??!
I think this concept doesn't relate to it

Comment: it does but not all of them, see the duplicate